# Input Validation for Java Program to check consecutive sequences

Tags: java

My Java program takes a sequence of numbers entered by a user, and should determine if the string is a series of up to 10 consecutive sequence numbers or if the number sequence contains the same number.

The numbers entered are separated by the dash character.  The program should display “**Correct consecutive sequence**”, “**Incorrect consecutive sequence**”, “**Pair of numbers found**”, “**Pair of numbers not found**” and/or “**Invalid Input**”.

I am struggling with input validation. I have been working on the code for hours. The iterative loop still runs if I input "**n**" for it to stop running, when the only thing it should accept is "**y**" or "**Y**". Also, the code breaks if I attempt to input a "w" when it should say "invalid input".

Lastly, a pair is not detected if it is not entered first. For example **3-3-4-5** is detected as a sequence with a pair, but it does not also include that is it consecutive. If I enter **3-4-5-5-6**, it will not detect the pair. I cannot figure out why it is doing this. Please Help. My code is shown below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication12 {

    /**

     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                char ch = 'y';

                //LOOP TO CONTINUOUSLY TAKE INPUT
        while(ch != 'n' || ch != 'N'){
                    System.out.println("Enter a sequence of numbers");
                    String num  = sc.next();

                    // WE WILL TAKE STRING INPUT SO WE WILL SPLIT IT WITH DELIMITER
                    String arr[] = num.split("-");
                    if(arr.length < 10){
                        int arrint[] = new int[arr.length];

                        for(int i=0;i< arr.length;i++){
                            arrint[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                        }


                        // PRESCRIBED CONDITOIONS AND USE OF 2 FUNCTIONS
                        if(arrint[0] == arrint[1]){
                            System.out.println("Pair Found");

                        }else if(arrint[0] == (arrint[1] + 1)){
                            new func().decreasing(arrint);
                        }else if(arrint[0] == (arrint[1] - 1)){
                            new func().increasing(arrint);
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                    }

                    //CODE THAT ASKS USER TO CONTINUE OR NOT
                    System.out.println("Want to enter more (Y/n)");
                    ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
                }
        }
}

    // CLASS THAT CONTAINS LOGIC OF FUNCITONS
class func{
    public void increasing(int[] arr){
        int flag = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length - 1;i++){
            if(!(arr[i] == (arr[i+1] - 1))){
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }else if(arr[i] == (arr[i+1])){
                flag = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 0){
            System.out.println("Incorrect consecutive sequence");
        }else if(flag == 1){
            System.out.println("Correct consecutive sequence");
        }else if(flag == 2){
            System.out.println("Pair of numbers found");
        }
    }

    public void decreasing(int[] arr){

        int flag = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length - 1;i++){
            if(!(arr[i] == (arr[i+1] + 1))){
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }else if(arr[i] == (arr[i+1])){
                flag = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 0){
            System.out.println("Incorrect consecutive sequence");
        }else if(flag == 1){
            System.out.println("Correct consecutive sequence");
        }else if(flag == 2){
            System.out.println("Pair of numbers found");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following statement will always be evaluated as true, **how can a character equals to two different characters at the same time?**

```
while (ch != 'n' || ch != 'N')
```

Change it to `while (ch != 'n' && ch != 'N')`